# indentation on C not working for 1st ten lines of code

Tags: c

The indentation in my program, which is achieved by `\t`, is only being displayed after the 10th day. I don't know what's wrong with it.

```
float penny= 0.01;
int days = 1;

while(31 >= days)
{
    printf("Day: %d \t Amount: %f\n", days, penny);
    days += 1;
    penny *= 2;
}
```

Comment: It's because of the TAB character which advances simple to the next modulo 8 column.

Comment: @MichaelWalz does that depend on the terminal, or is it standardized somewhere?

Comment: Try using `"%2d"` for the days instead. Or remove the space after printing the days.

Comment: @Kninnug see by answer below.

Answer (score 3):

It's because of the TAB character (`\t'`) which simply advances the cursor to the next modulo 8 column:

Illustration:

```
01234567012375670123456701234567 <-- column number modulo 8
|       |       |       |
Day: 9   Amount: 2.560000
Day: 10          Amount: 5.120000
Day: 11          Amount: 10.240000
```

Usually terminals behave like this, but I'm not sure if there is actually a standard which defines this.

Small program illustrating this behaviour:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int i,j,k;

  for (i = 0; i < 16; i++)
  {
    for (j = 0; j < 4; j++)
    {
      for (k = 0; k < i; k++)
      {
        printf ("*");
      }
      printf ("\t");
    }    
    printf ("\n");
  }
}
```

Output:

```
*       *       *       *
**      **      **      **
***     ***     ***     ***
****    ****    ****    ****
*****   *****   *****   *****
******  ******  ******  ******
******* ******* ******* *******
********        ********        ********        ********
*********       *********       *********       *********
**********      **********      **********      **********
***********     ***********     ***********     ***********
************    ************    ************    ************
*************   *************   *************   *************
**************  **************  **************  **************
*************** *************** *************** ***************
```

Answer (score 3):

`tab` is not a reliable alignment. You can specify number of spaces instead, for example:

`printf("Day: %-10dAmount: %f\n", days, penny);`

The `%-10d` specifier would print the day in exactly 10 spaces, left alignment.

Btw, see this [printf tricks](http://www.cypress.com/file/54761/download) for various tricks with `printf`, alignments, etc.

Comment: Great printf article!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
printf("Day: %d\t Amount: %f\n", days, penny);
```

Note the absence of a space before the first tab.

But perhaps using `%2d` with you original format gives a better result.

Comment: I tried removing the space. Now it doesn't indent any line of code.

Comment: @FahadSaleem, I'm not sure what you mean by *indent*, but removing the space does align all *Amount* columns.